# Importing Freshplanet ANE

Tags: air, air-native-extension

I discovered the great Freshplanet ANE repository https://github.com/freshplanet/
I'm trying to get the basic AirAlert to work but I can't work out how to resolve the import.

I build my Adobe AIR iOS app in IntelliJ and already have a couple of ANE successfully working. So what I did,

1. Copied the AirAlert.ane in my ane folder
2. Included in my App.xml extensions tag the relevant

   com.freshplanet.AirAlert
3. Added the ane in the Build Configuration of my project so that it has the right dependencies when I build in IntelliJ

But I can't seem to resolve the AirAlert in my code.
I tried with no luck.

```
import AirAlert; 

import com.freshplanet.AirAlert
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! After adding the ANE to all the build configurations under my Module Settings in IntelliJ.

I have about four different configurations, one for deploying to the emulator, one for the device etc and I had only added the ANE to the one deploying to the device as that was where I was interested in testing it.

But after I added it to all the other ones, I could resolve

```
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirAlert.AirAlert;
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: If you answered your own question please mark it 'accepted' so people will know a valid answer has been given and no more attention is needed.